# React-js with JSX setup starter kit

Tags: reactjs, setup-project

I just wanted to setup an react-js project with JSX, but I've searched on google for a good starter-kit but I really don't which is best to start with. I've tried to install this: [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) but I don't think thats an good one?

I know this is not the right place to ask this kind of questions but I really dont know it anymore..

I prefer with customisable bootstrap and scss or less compiler.

Comment: Take a look at boilerplate by Facebook: [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

Comment: @denysdovhan is that with customisable bootstrap in it/

Comment: @Begginerprogrammer sure, take a look at [Why Use This](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#why-use-this) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app//) that'll get you up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This question is difficult to answer without knowing your level of experience with React, and I fear the Stack Overflow community may block this question but nonetheless, I recommend checking out this site:

http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project

There is no one best solution when it comes to a starter kit, it can heavily depend on what type of application you're building and how much boilerplate you actually need. The link above provides a number of good starters to get you up and running quickly.

Comment: I dont see any good setup with bootstrap and gulp compile

Comment: There are a few Bootstrap kits out there, do you strictly have to use Gulp?

Comment: I like to use gulp because i can compile my less files

Comment: Have you used Webpack before? You can use Webpack to compile Less. There are some good kits available that use Bootstrap and Webpack, namely: https://github.com/dozoisch/koa-react-full-example. It does depend on how much knowledge you have though.

Comment: Never used webpack before